# Jenkins doesn't execute shell scripts in case of build failure

Tags: jenkins, hudson

I have a build step in Jenkins job, which executes a shell script. When build failes, it is omitted. What can I do to avoid this and execute my script with any build state?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to achieve this with [Any Build Step Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Any+Build+Step+Plugin). Use it to run your script as post-build action.

As stated in Any Build Step Plugin page, it also seems to require [Flexible Publish Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Flexible+Publish+Plugin) in order to allow running any build step as post-build action.

Comment: Not clear: I have all plugins installed and add conditional step after build. Doesn't work. Phing failes build and everything. It looks like this: [screenshot](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/45499397/ex.png)

Comment: Did you also install the "Flexible Publish Plugin", mentioned behind the link I put to answer? And did you add it as **Post-build action**?

Comment: No, there's no such Action in a Post-build action as a "Execute shell script". It is for publishing only.

Comment: I added it as Post-build action and put my script in it as a condition for running. And it works in this case, yet it's some kind of a hack.

Comment: Well, it's a "hack" only in the sense that it's running a normal build step as post-build action, instead of there being a dedicated "run shell command" post-build action. But adding things which must run anyway as post-build actions is not a hack, it's how Jenkins/Hudson work: stop actual build if a build step fails, but still do post-build actions to handle the result

Comment: I mean it's a hack because the chosen post-build action is artifact archivation, which I do just because I need something to be done after condition with my shell script is checked.